# Trying to understand a KeyError

Tags: python, python-imaging-library, keyerror

I have a code which compares image files in order to check if images in one directory match with any of the images in an other directory. I am not comparing file names, I am using `PIL`, the Python Imaging Library to actually compare the images.

My code returns a list with directory names that did not have a match, which is what I need. I have a 162 directories with images. My code checked 71 directories successfully and returned the desired output as expected. Then, starting at directory 72 I get the following: `KeyError: 'F:/162 pic sets ready/set72'` for all the rest of the directories.

This is the part I can not understand: if I move these directories to an other location, I still get the same error but if I copy the images from these directories into an other, empty directory and run the code on those directories I don't get the error.

```
from PIL import ImageChops
from PIL import Image
import math, operator
import os

path_images = ('C:/Users/Acer/Desktop/pics/')
list_to_match = []
for images in os.listdir(path_images):
    images_to_match = Image.open(path_images + images)
    list_to_match.append(images_to_match)
path_folders = ('F:/162 pic sets ready/')
d = {}
for dirpath, dirnames, filenames in os.walk(path_folders):
    if 'Thumbs.db' not in filenames:
        d[dirpath] = filenames
dict2 = {k: list(map(lambda x: (k+'/'+x ), v)) for k,v in d.items()}

c = 1
matches = []
folder_images_opened = []
while (c < 163):
    for im in dict2['F:/162 pic sets ready/set%s' % c]:
        test = Image.open(im)
        folder_images_opened.append(test)
    for images_to_find in list_to_match:
        if images_to_find in folder_images_opened:
            matches.append(c)
            print ('Folders where we found a match:', c)
            del folder_images_opened[:]    
    c = c+1
numbers = list(range(1,163))
numbers_filter = [i for i in numbers if i not in matches]
print ('Folders that does not have a match', numbers_filter)
```

This is the full Traceback:

```
KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-8-c663c9d71cf9> in <module>()
      4 
      5 while (c < 80):
----> 6     for im in dict2['F:/162 pic sets ready/set%s' % c]:
      7         test = Image.open(im)
      8         folder_images_opened.append(test)

KeyError: 'F:/162 pic sets ready/set72'
```

Comment: What error? Where? What are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: It'd help if you provided us with the *full traceback* of the exception you get.

Comment: @MartijnPieters Thanks for your comment Marttijn and thanks for taking a look and  editing my question as well. I posted the full traceback.

Comment: As your exception says, key `F:/162 pic sets ready/set72` is not present in `dict2`. In order to help you, we'll need [MVCE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: So how certain are you that a) `F:/162 pic sets ready/set72` exists and b) has no `Thumbs.db` file in that directory?

Comment: @MartijnPieters I am 100% certain that `F:/162 pic sets ready/set72` exists and I am using Windows so any of the directories might have the `Thumbs.db` files which I am handling with this `if 'Thumbs.db' not in filenames:` . Also, the `Thumbs.db` will have a different error message.

Comment: @JoeR: no, if there is a `Thumbs.db` then *that key won't be added to your dictionary*. No error message is printed then.

Comment: @JoeR: the error you'd get is a `KeyError` for that directory, because it was never added to `d`, and so never added to `dict2`.

Comment: @MartijnPieters This error message was printed when there was a `Thumbs.db` : `OSError: cannot identify image file 'F:/162 pic sets ready/set77/Thumbs.db'` I stopped this `Thumbs.db` issue with this line `if 'Thumbs.db' not in filenames:`

Comment: @JoeR: yes, and what do you think that means for those directories? You completely remove that directory from consideration. You don't remove `Thumbs.db` from the filenames, you removed the *whole directory*.

Comment: @JoeR: yes, and what do you think that means for those directories? You completely remove that directory from consideration. You don't remove `Thumbs.db` from the filenames, you removed the *whole directory*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are making two assumptions:

1. That the directory `F:/162 pic sets ready/set72` actually exists, and
2. That if it exists, there is no `Thumbs.db` filename in that directory.

If either assumption doesn't hold, then that path doesn't appear as a key in `dict2`.

You could simply test if the key exists first:

```
while (c < 163):
    dirname = 'F:/162 pic sets ready/set%s' % c
    if dirname not in dict2:
        print('{} does not exist or has a Thumbs.db file'.format(dirname))
        continue
    for im in dict2[dirname]:
        test = Image.open(im)
```

Rather than use a `while` loop and expect all `setx` directories to exist in sequence, loop over the keys of `dict2`; you could sort the keys even:

```
for dirname in sorted(dict2):
    directoryname = os.path.basename(dirname)  # 'set<somenumber>'
```

I *think* you just wanted to *skip `Thumbs.db`, not skip directories containing `Thumbs.db` (a big difference!). If so, test for the filename when processing the files, not when processing the directories:

```
for im in dict2['F:/162 pic sets ready/set%s' % c]:
    if os.path.basename(im) == 'Thumbs.db':
        continue
    test = Image.open(im)
    folder_images_opened.append(test)
```

and remove the `if 'Thumbs.db' not in filenames:` test altogether.

Comment: YES, of course, you're absolutely right! I appreciate it! Thanks so much for helping me with this.